# ¿Cómo hago en Java para parar la ejecución de un método hasta que el usuario presione un botón, para después continuar con el mismo método?

Tags: java, java-swing, botón

Estoy tratando de programar un método que requiere que el usuario pulse un botón para poder continuar con su ejecución. En concreto, se trata de un tablero y quiero pausar un método moverse hasta que el usuario pulse una casilla (que será a la que se mueva). El problema se resuelve usando "threads" y pausándolos en ese momento, pero me gustaría no tener que usar threads.

En la clase Tablero, cada casilla tiene un método que pone a la variable estática casilla (dentro de la clase Juego) a la casilla que ha sido pulsada. De esta forma, quiero esperar a que el usuario elija la casilla concreta para terminar la ejecución del método con operaciones sobre la misma.

He tratado de hacerlo con un bucle while con un centinela, en el que cuando se pulsa la casilla, se sale del mismo, pero el juego se queda congelado y no funcionan los botones.

Dejo una captura del método del que estoy hablando, donde lo he tratado de implementar con while y, como digo, no funciona.

```
public void moverse() {
        if(this.puedeMoverse(acciones, this.jugador)){
            acciones -= this.tablero.getCasilla(this.jugador.getCoordenada()).numZombies();
            Coordenada coordpartida = this.jugador.getCoordenada();
            tablero.iluminarCasillas(coordpartida, CasillaColor.VERDE, 1);
            JuegoGrafico.anunciar("ELIGE UNA CASILLA A LA QUE MOVERTE");
            while(casilla == null){}
            this.jugador.moverse(casilla.getCoordenada(), tablero);
            tablero.iluminarCasillas(coordpartida, CasillaColor.TRANSPARENTE, 1);
        } else {
            acciones += 1; 
    }
```

Los métodos de iluminar casillas sólo tienen utilidad gráfica, del mismo modo que anunciar.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido. Considera agregar tu código en formato texto, no como imagen. Eso ayuda a la lectura, para quien te vaya a ayudar.